# MQTT Unable to connect to server when using 3G

Tags: android, mqtt

When I try to run my app on a 3G connection it tries to connect for about 1 or 2 minutes and then it throws an exception, it works perfectly fine on wifi but not on 3G. I have tried with different peoples phone on different networks. Why wont it connect?

The exception it throws i an MQTT exception

```
Unable to connect to server
```

This is the MQTT class that i called it creates a new thread:

```
    public class MQTTService extends Service {

    ContextWrapper c = this;
    private MqttClient mqttClient;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://gateway.thebroker.com:1883";
            final String clientId = "android-client90";

            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                 try{


                    MqttClient mqttClient = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, clientId, new MemoryPersistence());
                    MqttConnectOptions opts = new MqttConnectOptions();
                    opts.setKeepAliveInterval(600);
                    opts.setUserName("nabin");
                    opts.setPassword("M4rk3r".toCharArray());   



                    Log.e("Before Callback", "Connecting..."); // Code works till here if callback is set then errors galore
                    //mqttClient.setCallback(handler.obtainMessage());
                    mqttClient.setCallback(new PushCallback(c));

                    mqttClient.connect(opts);

                        mqttClient.subscribe("house/pill/notification/bad");
                        mqttClient.subscribe("house/pill/notification/good");
                        mqttClient.subscribe("house/pill/notification/skip");
                        mqttClient.subscribe("house/pill/notification/alert");
                        mqttClient.subscribe("house/pill/notification/snooze");
                        mqttClient.subscribe("house/pill/schedule/response");
                        mqttClient.subscribe("house/pill/nextPill/response");

                        Log.e("CONNECTED!", "COOOONNECTED!!!!!");
                }catch(MqttException e){
                    Log.e("Internet Error", "No connection available  " + e.getMessage() );
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("ERRRRRORRRRR ", e.getMessage());
                }
            }           
    });  
    background.start();
    }
   }
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reach your server from another network, it needs a public ip address, unique to the world. From local network, through wifi it doesn't need to be public, request goes out, and it finds the address before going out the router.

You got private ip address at your internet provider, that means they give you ip through a router (NAT network). You can communicate out, but no one can reach you from another network.

If you call your internet provider, you can ask for your ip address to make it public.
It is experience for me, that 3 of 4 supporter don't know what public ip address is, they ask: you mean static? .. no .. public. Convince them.

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi connection seams to be in the same network that your broker, while your 3G connection tries to reach your broker via Internet.
Your 3G connection has to be able to reach the host `gateway.thebroker.com` at the port `1883`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cheap public IP address I recommend https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/   $5/month with hourly billing I mean...  $0.007/hour.   Then you can just easily install a Mosquitto Broker using any online tutorial.

Alternatively, you can use public open servers to test MQTT using any of these: http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/public_brokers  problem is, they might be slow since anyone can use them. But yeah, what others said its true. Your phone connect to it through WLAN (Wireless Local Area Network) however your 3G/4G service cant reach that address.